# Mysql Query Top 5 Services based on Sales

Tags: mysql

I have more then 5 services that use to sell but now i only want result in group of 5.
So i want to display my services name like service1, service2, service3, service4 and 5th will be rest services (which is left) totals.

I have fields

```
ID | Amt | Userid | Service | Date
```

I want exactly same ... thanks i hope i can explain u better now...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxy6D.gif pls click on the image to understand my question

I also forgot that to mentioned here i have to search between 2 dates and i don't want to put limit 5. So all the records between 2 dates are displayed and like image showing product name of top 4 and 5th one is contain all the other products.

Comment: There does not appear to be any sales data in your table.

Comment: So simple questions are answered daily here on stackoverflow, and well answered in any SLQ generic tutorial/guide/doc/book, why not studying some generic SQL before beginning to write code?

Comment: @mahesh-patil.. thanks guys atleast having look at my question before when i asked no body replied me... i have added images to my comments to specify my question. Please do let me know ur answers.. awaiting for u reply..

Comment: Can anyone pls help me to go further as i want to use Highcharts

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Sales is table here 

    SELECT Service, SUM(Amt) AS `sales_per_Service`
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY Service
    ORDER BY `sales_per_Service` DESC
    LIMIT 5;
```